# disappeared in the design tab

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-layout

I'm making an app. I was writing code, and I needed to go to my sign_dialog.xml. My code is there, but everything has disappeared in the design tab. Please tell me what could have happened ?[image]

Comment: Try the zoom buttons and the zoom reset button (1:1). If that does not help just close and reopen Android Studio. Sometimes it happens that something bugs out.

Comment: can you sharre your code? based on the screenshot the issue is not reproducible by others.

Answer (score 1):

This happens quite often with me too. All I really need to do is:

1. Restart the entire IDE
2. Build > Clean Project...
3. THIS ONE WORKS EVERYTIME : Under the design tab in the layout builder (top right), there is this red icon that has a "!" in it. They may be an error that says the layout could not be loaded correctly. Click on that and press the refresh button.

I hope these solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason it might be, you should remove autofillHints and all will be allright)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).